# Creating Hyper-V VMs with unique names using Powershell

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I'm trying to make some sort of script that creates a new VM, only need it to be told to create a unique VM name (with some sort of logic, if possible, to check for existing names and using something different automatically or just telling me to use something else) .  I understand a new VM is made using a unique GUID by default so there are no system conflicts, but I further need my script to go in and perform commands on the VM, such as starting the VMs, copying files onto it, etc. without a unique name I'm not sure how the script can automatically give commands to the right one.

For example, I have:

```
New-VM TestServer1 -AsJob -Generation 2 -MemoryStartupBytes 8192MB  -NoVHD -SwitchName VSwitch-1
```

but if a VM named 'TestServer1' already exists, and I were to have my script automatically run:

```
Start-VM TestServer1
```

both VMs would turn on...

Edit:

Also, I know one can export the results of creating a new VM using 'Out-File' but I don't know what cleanest way to format the output to be read back later.

Comment: Doesn't `New-VM` return the vm object? Couldn't you just capture and use that in later calls?

Comment: Correct.  Forgot to mention I've tried using the 'Out-File' cmdlet with the '-Append' switch to turn the exported file into a running list of all VMs , just not sure the best approach for formatting so they can be read when creating another VM

Comment: Wait, what? I'm talking about in the script where you create the new VM. It doesn't matter if the name collides (unless you care about that specifically) because you can just save the returned VM and use that during that script execution (instead of operating by name).

Comment: PS C:\Windows\system32> New-VM Test-Server1

Name         State CPUUsage(%) MemoryAssigned(M) Uptime   Status            
----         ----- ----------- ----------------- ------   ------            
Test-Server1 Off   0           0                 00:00:00 Operating normally
Not sure what you refer to when you say object?

Comment: Is this 2008 or 2012? In 2012 at least the return value of the `New-VM` function is a vm object. Save it `$vm = New-VM ....` and then you can use `-VM $vm` in later hyper-v function calls. If you don't save it then powershell will "render" the object as text for you since it can't stuff an object at the display.

Comment: Is there no Get-VM function? `if(Get-VM "TESTSERVER1") { Write-Output "Dude... server already exists Pick a new name or I am going to add a unique ID to end."} else { New-VM "TESTSERVER1"....and stuff }`